# shell command error Syntax error: "done" unexpected (expecting "do")

Tags: php, shell, ubuntu, sh

Im getting the error of

`Syntax error: "done" unexpected (expecting "do")` this, if I run the following shell file,

```
LOG=/xxx/yyy.txt
while read folder day X
do
    echo "$(date)"
    find ${folder} -mtime +${day} -type f | while read line
 do
    rm ${line}
    echo "deleted : $line"
 done
done < foldersToDelete.list >> $LOG
```

can anyone please help me to fix this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Feels little bad to answering to my question,

Anyway I fixed this,

Problem is my foldersToDelete.list file,

there leading char like this "^M" in the end of line was the killer, because of windows to ubuntu problem,

after I cleared that the above code was working fine.

Comment: Answering your own question is [fine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question).  Please consider marking your answer as accepted so this no longer shows up as unresolved.  Thanks.

Comment: sorry tripleee my reputaion is quite low so I have to wait 2 days to accept my own answer.